# Android: Google Sign In - difference between 'DEFAULT_SIGN_IN' and 'DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN'

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin, google-play-games, googlesigninaccount

I am trying to implement a Google Sign In into my app in AndroidStudio. I have it working with:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().requestServerAuthCode(clientID).build();
```

I have my client ID correctly set up to the Web Application Client ID from the API console and SHA1 is definitely set up correctly.

When i change to this (using DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN instead):

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().requestServerAuthCode(clientID).build();
```

I get an error with message as null and status code as 12501.

What is the difference between DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN and DEFAULT_SIGN_IN? Do i need to do something different for the games sign in?

Here is all my code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
String clientID;
int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    clientID = getString(R.string.client_id);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().requestServerAuthCode(clientID).build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    signInSilently();

}

private void signInSilently(){
    mGoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = task.getResult();
                setText(signedInAccount.getEmail(), signedInAccount.getDisplayName());
            }else{
                interactiveSignIn();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void interactiveSignIn(){
    Intent i = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(i, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if(result.isSuccess()){
            GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
            setText(signedInAccount.getEmail(), signedInAccount.getDisplayName());
        }else{
            String message = "ERROR: " + result.getStatus().getStatusMessage() + " - CODE: " + result.getStatus().getStatusCode();
            showAlert(message);
        }
    }
}

void showAlert(String message){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message).setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
}

void setText(String email, String name){
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Test_TextView);

    tv.setText("EMAIL: " + email + "   NAME: " + name);
}
```

}

Comment: If you check this [blog](http://www.googblogs.com/tag/google-play-game-services/), here's how `DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN` was implemented. `GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();`. Check if this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One difference is that DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN requests the [Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Games.html#SCOPE_GAMES_LITE) scope.

This is required to use Google Play Games apis within your application.

(Note: I am not 100% certain that it is the lite scope. It may request Games.SCOPE_GAMES instead. However, a [search](https://developers.google.com/s/results/?q=Scope_Games&p=%2Fandroid%2F) on SCOPE_GAMES in the documentation brings up deprecated interfaces whose new alternatives all require SCOPE_GAMES_LITE)

However, in order to sign in to Google Play Games, your app must be set up with Google Play Games Services.

Refer to the official [guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) on how to do this.

Follow the instructions carefully the first time, as any little mistake will leave you with an unsuccessful sign-in.

After the set up, you may want to look at the Games-specific sign-in [guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin).