# Google Sign In Failed ( ApiException: 8 )

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin

When I try to sign in by google I get this exception

> 2020-11-12 13:32:51.571 7351-7351/com.test.app W/aaab: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8

What does it mean?

*Code*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).build());
    Button btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), 100);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.w("aaab","" + task.getException());
        }
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
        } catch (ApiException ignored) {

        }
    }
}}
```

*Here is the Manifests..........................................................*

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.app">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="892959183721" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229264/android-google-sign-in-fails-with-error-code-8-no-message

Comment: @KrzysztofKubicki But it works when I change DEFAULT_Games_SIGN_IN To DEFAULT_SIGN_IN

Comment: You didn't put that in you question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49017777/android-google-sign-in-difference-between-default-sign-in-and-default-game

Comment: @KrzysztofKubicki I don't know why there is a lack of tutorial about Google Play Games Services

Comment: Do you have it installed on the device you're using to test?

Comment: I had solved the problem, Thanks.