# Login with gmail is causing error which isnt specific what is wrong?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-authentication

Good morning y'all im having this issue when i run my app with my emulator and click on the login with gmail i get this error

```
W/System.err: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8: 
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@19.0.0:9)
        at com.example.soulforge.fragments.LoginFragment.onActivityResult(LoginFragment.java:161)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:170)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5008)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5056)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

And I dont understand why and im hoping someone does as it doesnt specify whats wrong

My LoginFragment part that causes the error:

```
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                assert account !=null;
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's does `e.getMessage()` say?

Comment: I cant get the try and catch to work so I cant find what it says I tried to also use https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in to create it

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803668/google-sign-in-failed-apiexception-8